# Is there a barcode scanner SDK that works with iPad 2?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, sdk, barcode

Is there a barcode scanner SDK that works with iPad 2?

I've tried RedLaser 3.0 (I have an account through them) and they don't have native iPad 2 app support... only iPhone apps run on the iPad 2 work. I also tried an iPad 2 hack of ZBar (open source) and although it works, it doesn't work very well.

Any other options out there?

Comment: I agree with the ZBar comment.  It does not work very well on the iPad 2.  Could it be the camera or is it the library?

Comment: Obvious is the camera. 0.7 MP is very small. To compare, take a picture of iPad 2 and iPhone and open in the computer. See how you have more details in iPhone.

Comment: Have you figured this out ever? Z bar sdk was working for me earlier. but once I restore my iPad2 this is not working. Auto focus or any image processing is not working either. This was working earlier restoring... can you suggest me what to do?

Comment: Any experiences with the front camera of the iPad 2? Is barcode detection possible without autofocus?

Comment: Nope never did. ZBar will not be fully supporting it because the resolution of the camera on the iPad 2 is worse than that of the iPhone 2G (original iPhone). Here's hoping iPad 3 has a better cam. I refuse to shell out $2k to use a barcode scanner in my iPad apps. I'll just wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scandit SDK barcode scanner from [Mirasense](http://www.mirasense.com). Their latest version was updated to optimally support the iPad 2.

Comment: Thanks, I just sent them an email. What are the costs of using this SDK?

Comment: Scandit license fees are available here: http://www.scandit.com/scandit-sdk/pricing/ and start at USD 2,500

Answer (score 3):

ZBar is the best to use. There are a post [about it](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/forums/forum/1072195/topic/4422747). The unique difference of zbar to iphone and ipad is the screen size, so it is a "little native". But take in mind that [the camera of IPad 2 is very bad...](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/forums/forum/1072195/topic/4509971).  **The iPad 2 have 0.7 MP camera** (back) and 0.4 MP (front), so will be dificult decode same symbols. It even didn't have autofocus. Only to say, the first iPhone have a 2.0 MP. (Today is 5.0 MP)

Test with a iPhone program in your iPad if it decode what you want (make no difference the result). If it work, be happy, if not, next year buy the iPad 3.

--Edit--

Now the ZBar suport iPad 2

Comment: I did this exact thing. It still sucks. The problem with ZBar is that it doesn't do any kind of image processing to focus the barcode if it's blurry, like RedLaser does. Zbar is decent only when the focus on the barcode is good. Otherwise ZBar sucks. That is why they don't support the iPhone 3G.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at ScannerKit. It's available for both iOS and Android.

ScannerKit for iOS: http://shopsavvy.mobi/sdk/

Comment: Do they currently support iPad 2 natively?

Comment: My guess is anything with a camera is supported but your milage may vary as the camera on the iPad 2 has a lower resolution in comparison to the iPhone.