# Barcode scanning on iPad2

Tags: iphone, barcode

Is barcode scanning possible on iPad2?

Most of the places, I found that it works for iPhone.

And here - [Is there a barcode scanner SDK that works with iPad 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916385/is-there-a-barcode-scanner-sdk-that-works-with-ipad-2), I found that it is possible on iPad2.

Has anyone tried for barcode scanning on iPad2?

Is barcode scanning possible on iPad2? If no, can anyone give reasons?

Comment: Yes as that post suggests its possible. Is there any reason you don't want to try out some code samples before you post a question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a barcode scanner SDK that works with iPad 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916385/is-there-a-barcode-scanner-sdk-that-works-with-ipad-2)

Answer (score 2):

Neha, I think that is very hard, because iPad2 camera not have autofocus, and to implement barcode reader this resource is very important. Maybe you will have sucess with QRCodes readers, in iPhone 3G (camera without autofocus) it works, but more complex barcodes like 2of5 does not. Only iPhones 3GS, 4, 4S have camera with autofocus.

Answer (score 1):

Try our free app [pic2shop](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pic2shop-shop-by-barcode/id308740640?mt=8) and the ad-free version optimized for iPad, [Barcode Scanner HD](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/barcode-scanner-hd/id425162295?mt=8)

They both scan UPC and EAN perfectly on the iPad 2 (and the iPod Touch).

The SDK is available under a commercial license: http://www.visionsmarts.com/products/VSBarcodeReader/VSBarcodeReader.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [ZBar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar).

Comment: ZBar for iPad not detecting barcodes

Comment: Yes even i have tried with ZBar sample codes. It was working on iPhone but when i upgraded code for iPad 2 compatability, but it was not being able to detecting that barcode. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I used ZBar for barcode scanning on iPad. Now it is working fine. Only the problem I am getting is - camera orienation is different than my application. my app is in landscape orientaion. Where as camera is opening in portait oriention.

I used following code:-


ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;

Comment: i afraid coz apps don't have any control over cam. please take it as correct answer if its working.